# Creating a ScheduledTask in PowerShell to run when any network is available

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to use `New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet` and `Register-ScheduledTask` to create a Scheduled Task using PowerShell that will run an app when any network connection is available after startup or log on.

So far I have something like this:

```
$taskAction =  New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "MyApp.exe" -Argument "/someparams"
$taskTriggers = @()
$taskTriggers += New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn
$taskTriggers += New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
$taskSettings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable -MultipleInstances IgnoreNew -RestartCount 3 -RestartInterval (New-Timespan -Minutes 2)

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "MyTask" -TaskPath "\MyTasks" -Description "A test task" -Action $taskAction -Settings $taskSettings -Trigger $taskTriggers
```

This *appears* to work and a new task is visible in the Task Scheduler app, but if I try to look at the *Conditions* tab of that task then Task Scheduler crashes, which can't be good!

I *think* this might be because the [Microsoft documentation for New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasksettingsset) says that I need to also specify `-NetworkId` and `-NetworkName` when using `-RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable`

Unfortunately I can't find any documentation that says what the valid values are for `NetworkId` or where I can find them. It's also not clear if there is a way to specify "any network": the Task Scheduler app seems to have that as an option, but it causes the same crash!

Comment: I think the network identifier might be the instance ID of a given connection profile, try discovery with `Get-NetConnectionProfile |Select Interface*,Name,InstanceID`

Comment: Is $taskSettings null?  Add to code for debugging :  $taskSettings | format-List

Comment: When I selected that option in the GUI and set it to Any Connection, then got the task information on PowerShell, it had a blank entry for the network settings, so you might be able to provide empty strings as values for ID and Name to allow any network connection.

Comment: Interestingly `Get-NetConnectionProfile` that @MathiasR.Jessen suggested, fails on my target machine. Looks like it is locked down so that the Network Connection Broker service is not running. Guess that may explain the crashes.